# Fixpoint with Prop inhabitant as argument

Tags: coq

Consider the definition of `find` in [the standard library](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Lists.List.html#find), which as the type `find: forall A : Type, (A -> bool) -> list A -> option A`.

Of course, `find` has to return an `option A` and not an `A` because we don't know wether there is a "valid" element in the list.

Now, say I find this definition of `find` painful, because we have to deal with the option, even when we are sure that such an element exists in the list.

Hence, I'd like to define `myFind` which additionnaly takes a proof that there is such an element in the list. It would be something like:

```
Variable A: Type.
Fixpoint myFind 
  (f: A -> bool) 
  (l: list A) 
  (H: exists a, In a l /\ f a = true): A :=
...
```

If I am not mistaken, such a signature informally says: "Give me a function, a list, and a proof that you have a "valid" element in the list".

My question is: how can I use the hypothesis provided and define my fixpoint ?

What I have in mind is something like:

```
match l with
| nil => (* Use H to prove this case is not possible *)
| hd :: tl => 
  if f hd
  then hd
  else 
    (* Use H and the fact that f hd = false 
       to prove H': exists a, In a tl /\ f a = true *)
    myFind f tl H'
end.
```

---

An bonus point would be to know whether I can embbed a property about the result directly within the type, for instance in our case, a proof that the return value `r` is indeed such that `f r = true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can implement this `myFind` function by structural recursion over the input list. In the case of empty list the `False_rect` inductive principle is our friend because it lets us switch from the logical world to the world of computations. In general we cannot destruct proofs of propositions if the type of the term under construction lives in `Type`, but if we have an inconsistency the system lets us.

We can handle the case of the non-empty input list by using the *convoy pattern* (there is a number of great answers on Stackoverflow explaining this pattern) and an auxiliary lemma `find_not_head`.

It might be useful to add that I use the convoy pattern twice in the implementation below: the one on the top level is used to let Coq know the input list is empty in the first `match`-branch -- observe that the type of `H` is different in both branches.

```
From Coq Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.
Set Implicit Arguments.

(* so we can write `f a` instead of `f a = true` *)
Coercion is_true : bool >-> Sortclass.

Section Find.
Variables (A : Type) (f : A -> bool).

(* auxiliary lemma *)
Fact find_not_head h l : f h = false ->
  (exists a, In a (h :: l) /\ f a) ->
  exists a, In a l /\ f a.
Proof. intros E [a [[contra | H] fa_true]]; [congruence | now exists a]. Qed.

Fixpoint myFind (l : list A) (H : exists a : A, In a l /\ f a) : {r : A | f r} :=
  match l with
  | [] => fun H : exists a : A, In a [] /\ f a =>
           False_rect {r : A | f r} 
                      match H with
                      | ex_intro _ _ (conj contra _) =>
                        match contra with end
                      end
  | h :: l => fun H : exists a : A, In a (h :: l) /\ f a =>
               (if f h as b return (f h = b -> {r : A | f r})
                then fun Efh => exist _ h Efh
                else fun Efh => myFind l (find_not_head Efh H)) eq_refl
  end H.
End Find.
```

Here is a simplistic test:

```
From Coq Require Import Arith.
Section FindTest.
Notation l := [1; 2; 0; 9].
Notation f := (fun n => n =? 0).
Fact H : exists a, In a l /\ f a.
Proof. exists 0; intuition. Qed.

Compute myFind f l H.
(*
     = exist (fun r : nat => f r) 0 eq_refl
     : {r : nat | f r}
*)
End FindTest.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Program` to help you construct the proof arguments interactively.  You fill in as much as you can in the program body and leave `_` blanks that you get to fill in later with proof tactics.

```
Require Import List Program.

Section Find.

  Variable A : Type.
  Variable test : A -> bool.

Program Fixpoint FIND l (H:exists a, test a = true /\ In a l) :  {r | test r = true} :=
  match l with
  | [] => match (_:False) with end
  | a::l' => if dec (test a) then a else FIND l' _
  end.

Next Obligation.
  firstorder; congruence.
Defined.

End Find.
```

`Program` is a little better at not forgetting information when you do case analysis (it knows the convoy pattern) but it is not perfect, hence the use of `dec` in the `if` statement.

(Notice how Coq was able to handle the first obligation, to construct a term of type `False`, all by itself!)